How to check if a type is in a TypeVar or not
I am looking for a way to check (True or False) if a type exist in a TypeVar:
from typing import TypeVar 
number = TypeVar("number" ,int ,float)

num: number = 3.14

I am looking for sth like this:
 print(type(num) in number) # check if "float" is in "number"


The constraints of a type variable is stored as a tuple in the __constraints__ attribute according to the documentation, so you can simply perform the following check:
type(num) in number.__constraints__


Important note: using such runtime checks is strongly discouraged. This can break for multitude of reasons, starting from int being a subtype of float in static python but not at runtime and up to using stringified annotations (e.g. forward references). Also checking the exact type is almost always a bad idea: you don't want to reject a class Child for a TypeVar bound to its Parent.
